# Enable WS traffic on a VPC Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am using API Gateway and some Lambdas for a WebSocket API. However, I am using Aurora DB, which requires a VPC. onconnect and ondisconnect lambdas are behaving fine and adding/removing connections, so HTTPs traffic is working fine, however, the onmessage lambda does not send out the messages to an outside connection if it is on the VPC.

I do not necessarily need the onmessage lambda to be on VPC, as I can use another lambda for retrieving the necessary data from the database, but sending data over via lambda invocation seems to also not work from a lambda on a VPC.

I was wondering if anyone could direct me to settings responsible for enabling WS connections to outside connections or, even better, at least for communication between lambdas outside and inside the VPC.

On a semi-related note, a very similar WS setup is working fine without a VPC.

Comment: *"so HTTPS traffic is working fine"*  Not clear what this statement means.  HTTPS to/from what, to/from what?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry, I was referring to the onconnect/ondisconnect endpoints on the WS API. When connection requests are made to the API the connection ID gets added to the Aurora DB